# extract identity when I read a nsdata from a p12 file

Tags: objective-c, ios, openssl

I can extract identity when I read a nsdata from a p12 file from my bundle.

```
NSData *PKCS12Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"p12"]];
```

But when I stored it as blob and try to create the nsdata

```
PKCS12 *newp12;

using NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&p12ptr length:length];
```

it failed ....error code -26275 osstatus. both occassion nsdata shows the same bytes .. any encodeing issue ? 
please help

I am extracting identity using following code

```
securityError = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef)inPKCS12Data,(CFDictionaryRef)optionsDictionary,&items);

    if (securityError == 0) { 
        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *outIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
        *outTrust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
    } else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed with error code %d",(int)securityError);
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by ‘stored it as a blob’? Is `newp12` the same as `p12ptr`? If not, what’s the type of `p12ptr`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation for the initWithBytes method:

> **initWithBytes:length:**
>
> Returns a data object initialized by adding to it a
>   given number of bytes of data copied
>   from a given buffer.
>
> - (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length

And your code is doing this:

```
NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&p12ptr length:length];
```

You can see that for the first argument you are passing in the address to p12ptr. I am making the assumption that this variable isnt a byte? Which if it isn't then you are passing an incorrect pointer to the function and NSData is trying to initialize itself with *length* number of bytes from some random location in memory space.

Could you please post the code where you declare p12ptr and also where you initialize it?